# Call date-picker view on custom button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I use this [library](https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker) for date-picker. I am trying to open date-picker on clicking by custom button. 
This is my default input and it works fine.

```
<input name="pickerFromDate" date-time ng-model="model[options.key]" id="pickerFromDate" min-view="month" class="edb-input input-group-input"
 placeholder="{{to.placeholder}}" max-date="maxDate" date-change="changeMinValue" format="MMM DD, YYYY" validation="required"
 watch-direct-changes="true" />
```

And here is my custom button, by clicking on this button i want to open my calendar view, like i a'm clicking on input.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="setFocus($event);">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</button>
```

In my directive-controller I declared this functions

```
$scope.setFocus = function(data) {
    let input = $(data.target).closest('.cv-form-section').find('input');
    input.click();
};
```

I find the input, but triggering "click" or "focus" event cause an error.

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
```

Comment: can you please add a snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Import `$timeout` into your controller head setting
2. Use it:

> ```
> $scope.setFocus = function(data) {
>     let input = $(data.target).closest('.cv-form-section').find('input');
>     $timeout(function(){
>       input.click();
>     })
> };
> ```